# How to appear in console, if the element is exist on the page

Tags: java, selenium

Want to find the element by cssSelector and appear in console text, if it exist on the page.

Here how I tried to do it:

```
public void ClickOnTheButton() {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://ain.ua");

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#header > div.header-wrap > div > div.menu-container > div.right-side-menu > div > span.searchform > span")).click();
    if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#subbody > div.header-search-container"))) {
        System.out.println("Button is works correct");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find and insert elements into a collection. And later you can check if the collection is empty or not. If not empty, you can print the required text in console.

Example:

```
List<WebElement> follow = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"new_user\"]/div[3]/button"));

if (follow.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println("The element exist");
}
```

Comment: Using findElement (singular, ie no 's') asserts when you don't find the element, whereas findElements (plural, ie with 's') returns an empty list. So if you are trying to create an isPresent(WebElement) or isExists(WebElement) use findElements , as suggested here.